# Appending value in JavaScript on listbox

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How do I get values from all the options rather than just the selected values in a listbox?

```
<select name="name" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

I actually have a JavaScript to append values from 1 listbox to another. A solution I did was to create a hidden field, whenever one appends to the other, it appends to the hidden field as well but apparently I might have append to the hidden field wrongly with

```
hiddenField.append(jQuery(this));
```

I'm getting a form post data

Answer (score 1):

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("name");
var i;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
  console.log(x.options[i].text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very clear, but I'm assuming you wanted to fetch the value of all of the selected values, not all of the values in the entire list. I.e. if a person has selected 1 and 2, you can't get that information from using `.value`. Instead, you'll use `.selectedOptions`.

So if you were to use `document.getElementsByName("name")[0].selectedOptions` the output would be `[
<option value=​"1">​1​</option>​
, 
<option value=​"2">​2​</option>​
]`

You can also get specific selection's values by doing: `document.getElementsByName("name")[0].selectedOptions[x].value` where `x` is the position.